# Associate letters and numbers, and calculate sum of string in Python

Tags: python

I am currently learning Python for a while and made a program called *character counter*; which you input a text/word and it prints out a number e.g. `abc = 6` because `a = 1`, `b = 2`, `c = 3` and so on.

And I found out while coding, it took me very long because I had to assign values to each alphabet (like the examples I showed before) and the whole thing took more than 80 lines.

Is there any way I could simplify this?

```
alpha = str(input('enter something '))
i = 0

beta = list(alpha)
z = len(beta)


while z > 0:
    if beta[i] == "a":
        beta[i] = 1

    if beta[i] == 'b':
        beta[i] = 2

    if beta[i] == 'c':
        beta[i] = 3

    if beta[i] == "d":
        beta[i] = 4

    if beta[i] == 'e':
        beta[i] = 5

    if beta [i] == 'f':
         beta[i] = 6 

    if beta[i] == 'g':
        beta[i] = 7

    if beta[i] == 'h':
        beta[i] = 8
    
    if beta[i] == 'i':
        beta[i] = 9

    if beta[i] == 'j':
        beta[i] = 10
    
    if beta[i] == 'k':
        beta[i] = 11
    
    if beta[i] == 'l':
        beta[i] = 12
    
    if beta[i] == 'm':
        beta[i] = 13

    if beta[i] == 'n':
        beta[i] = 14

    if beta[i] == 'o':
        beta[i] = 15

    if beta[i] == 'p':
        beta[i] = 16

    if beta[i] == 'q':
        beta[i] = 17

    if beta[i] == 'r':
        beta[i] = 18
    
    if beta[i] == 's':
        beta[i] = 19

    if beta[i] == 't':
        beta[i] = 20

    if beta[i] == 'u':
        beta[i] = 21
    
    if beta[i] == 'v':
        beta[i] = 22

    if beta[i] == 'w':
        beta[i] = 23
    
    if beta[i] == 'x':
        beta[i] = 24
    
    if beta[i] == 'y':
        beta[i] = 25
    
    if beta[i] == 'z':
        beta[i] = 26


    i= i + 1
    z = z - 1

print(sum(beta))
```

I think that there should be a simpler way of writing it, but I currently dont know how.

Answer (score 0):

The 'condensed' way of writing what you have is to put them all in a dict:

```
mapping = {
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2,
    ...
    'z': 26
}

...

while z > 0:
    beta[i] = mapping[beta[i]]
    i = i + 1
    z = z - 1
```

The ideal way, though, is to construct the dict in a single line, dynamically:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
# ascii_lowercase == 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
# see also https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html

mapping = dict(zip(ascii_lowercase, range(1, 27)))
# range(1, 27) yields (1, 2, ..., 25, 26)
# zip() will yield 2-tuples between corresponding elements, a=1, b=2, ..., z=26
# dict() can take a list of 2-tuples, and interpret them as keys and values respectively
```

Comment: You can pass `enumerate ` a start value: `dict(enumerate(ascii_lowercase, 1))`  ;-)

Comment: @schwobaseggl `enumerate()` gives the index first and the letter second, which is the opposite order of what we'd want in this case

Comment: You could use `dict` comprehension maybe ?

Comment: True, `c: i for i, c in ...` then. BUt `enumerate` should be the tool to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some utils such as [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), [`string.ascii_lowercase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase), and [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as low

num = {c: i for i, c in enumerate(low, 1)}

def total(alpha):
    return sum(num[char] for char in alpha)

>>> total("abc")
6
>>> total("abcd")
10
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this would be to use the ord() function

Unicode characters have an integer associated with them that we can get using ord(character)

letters a-z go from 97 to 122

So you could do something like this

```
def counter():

    letters = input("whatever")

    # incase non letters passed
    if not letters.isalpha():
        return "not letters"

    output = 0
    for letter in letters.lower():
        output += ord(letter) - 96

    return output
```